# Linq query to select an item, with a parameter in a collection

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I'm struggling with a linq query working within an asp.net QueryString method. I've tried various things, but still not quite getting it right.

My model is:

```
public class SportType
{
    public int SportTypeID {get; set;}
    public string SportTypeName {get; set;}
}

public class Company
{
    public int CompanyID {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public ICollection<SportType> sportTypes {get; set;}
}
```

There is a sport type table in the database with values such as (1=Football, 2=golf, 3=cricket) etc.

A company can have none/one/more than one sport type.
I want to select all companies with a specific sport type.

But this linq query gives a compiler error:

Argument 1: cannot convert from System.Linq.IQueryable to MyNamespace.SportType

```
public IQueryable<Company> GetCompanies([QueryString("sportTypeID")] int? sportTypeID)
{
    var db = new MyDatabaseContext();
    IQueryable<Company>query = db.Companies;
    if (sportTypeID.HasValue && sportTypeID>0)
    {
        query = query.Where(theCompany => theCompany.sportTypes.Contains(db.SportTypes.Select(sp => sp.SportTypeID == sportTypeID)));
    }
    return query;
}
```

Can anyone help?
thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are having error due to return value of

```
db.SportTypes.Select(sp => sp.SportTypeID == sportTypeID)
```

line. It returns a collection(with, probably, many values) of your SportType instances while Contains method expects only single SportyType instance.
Try this:

```
public IQueryable<Company> GetCompanies([QueryString("sportTypeID")] int sportTypeID)
{
    var db = new MyDatabaseContext();
    IQueryable<Company>query = db.Companies;
    if (sportTypeID.HasValue && sportTypeID>0)
    {
        query = query.Where(theCompany => theCompany.sportTypes.Any(stype => stype.SportTypeID == sportTypeID)));
    }
    return query;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be more efficient than Blablablaster's answer:

```
public IQueryable<Company> GetCompanies([QueryString("sportTypeID")] int? sportTypeID)
{
    var db = new MyDatabaseContext();
    IQueryable<Company>query = db.Companies;
    if (sportTypeID.HasValue && sportTypeID>0)
    {
        return query.Join(db.SportTypes, o => o.CompanyID, i => i.CompanyID, (o, i) => new {
                        Company = o,
                        HasSportType = i.SportTypeID == sportTypeID
                    })
                    .Where(x => x.HasSportType)
                    .Select(x => x.Company)
                    .Distinct();
    }
    return query;
}
```

The `Any` command is not deferred, which probably isn't desirable in this case.

Comment: I've sent many .Any calls into the database.  It certainly translates.  Have you tried it?  Also - Join->Distinct is no good...

Comment: Thanks David.  Since I didn't try it, I was under the impression that there was a database query for each `.Any`.  Fortunately, LINQ is smarter than that.